# Create user in django 1.9 with email as username get duplicate

Tags: python, django, email

I have a simple class to create users with a random password and using emails as username, and it works. But I get duplicate users registered.

```
        if request.user.is_anonymous():
    signup_form.save(request)
            email = signup_form.cleaned_data.get('email')
            pwd = get_random_string(length=16)
            user = User.objects.create_user(email, email, pwd )
            customer, created = Customer.objects.get_or_create(user=user)
    customer.mobile = request.POST.get('mobile', '')
            customer.save()
            user = authenticate(username=user.username, password=pwd)
            login(request, user)
            user.first_name = extend_form.cleaned_data.get('name')
            user.last_name = extend_form.cleaned_data.get('surname')
            user.save()
```

A example, with `user@email.com` I get two users accounts registered:

1. `exampleuser@email.com` registered with the right relations of customer objects and `first_name`/`last_name` filled
2. `exampleuser` with email `exampleuser@email.com`, but without any relations of customer and empty `first_name/last_name`

Comment: Just to save you a headache later on, this won't work, Django's username field has a max length of 30 which fills up very fast when you try to insert an email address into it. You need to make your own custom user model

Comment: It looks like `signup_form.save()` creates a user, and then you create another user with `User.objects.create_user()`.